# Timecode Tags Calculation

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a beginner in python and I have a small question. There is a plain text with timing tags (hours:minutes:seconds). 'Some text 1' and 'Some text 3' are advertisements. I need to calculate the total duration of the advertisement in the text. How to do it?

<time=”08:00:00"><type=ad> some text 1 <time=”08:02:24"></type=ad> some text 2 <time=”08:10:18"><type=ad> some text 3 <time=”08:12:20"></type=ad>

Answer (score 0):

If each time stamp is preceded by the string, then you should find the number of occurrences in the string using the count method e.g. `num = string.count("time=")`

Then you can use a for loop over this range to find the actual strings.

```
times = []
index = 0

for i in range(0, num):
    time = string.index("time=", index)  # search for "time=", starting from index
    times.append(string[time+6:time+14])
    index = time+1
```

Then you can split the strings into hour-minute-seconds integer strings in a list like so:

```
hms = [timestr.split(":") for timestr in times]
```

In all, the following full code should work sufficiently

```
string = '<time=”08:00:00"><type=ad> some text 1 <time=”08:02:24"></type=ad> some text 2 <time=”08:10:18"><type=ad> some text 3 <time=”08:12:20"></type=ad>'
num = string.count("time=")

times = []
index = 0

for i in range(0, num):
    time = string.index("time=", index)  # search for "time=", starting from index
    times.append(string[time+6:time+14])
    index = time+1

print(times)

hms = [timestr.split(":") for timestr in times]

print(hms)
```

Leave a comment if you have any questions

Comment: CmdCoder858, thank you so  much! I'm still just learning and therefore, perhaps, asking strange questions ))) I'll try to do it the way you wrote!